# How to get the full URL that is used to load the app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application and I need to know the full URL of it inside the app - the address the user put into the browser to get there.

If I use Router or ActivatedRoute I only the the path, but not the full URL.

```
constructor (private rt : Router)
{
}

ngOnInit ()
{
  console.log (this.rt.url);
}
```

e.g. app is under https://localhost/blabla I not only want /blabla but the I need the full URL.

Comment: Please make it an answer so I can give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to use the browser's native [`window.location.href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) to read the current URL.